# C code to check if unsigned short contains a particular byte

Tags: c, binary

I have an `unsigned short` value. It is binary data sampled from a radio source. I'd like to check if the data contains a particular byte, a signature byte.

To illustrate, the `unsigned short` might be

```
0100 1010 0111 0101 /* 0x4A75 */
```

and I want to check if it contains the byte

```
1010 0111 /* 0xA7 */
```

anywhere. The data being checked will change each time I check but the signature will be constant.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the signature byte on a nibble boundary?

Comment: "Sampled from a radio source" sounds like analog, but I guess it's the output of a digital radio. Most bit-stream transmission formats involve some kind of parity, synchronization, and encoding. You would never just look for an unaligned bit pattern like that.

Comment: You could probably use a variation of KMP or B-M algorithm to compute the right amount of shift for a given mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bit shift to the right 8 times (the 9-th one isn't used) and check for equality.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned short data = 0x4a75;
    unsigned char byte = 0xa7;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i <= 16 - 8; i++){
        if(byte == (unsigned char)data){
            printf("found signature (offset %i)\n", i);
            break;
        }
        data >>= 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mostly good but you actually need to do 9 checks (shift by 0 through 8 inclusive)

Answer (score 2):

Compare the least significant byte of your `short` object with `0xA7` (i.e., `1010 0111`) in a loop and shift your `short` value one bit to the right at each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bit shifting, you can also use lookup tables:

```
const unsigned short signature[3] = {0xA700, 0x0A70, 0x00A7};
const unsigned short mask[3] = {0xFF00, 0x0FF0, 0x00FF};
```

You can analyze the data to see if it has the signature in a simple `for` loop:

```
bool signatureFound = false;
int i;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if((data & mask[i]) == signature[i])
    {
        signatureFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The test is no good, e.g. 0x00FF will be considered to match.

Answer (score 0):

If you are desperate for speed, a (mere!) 8192 bytes of memory will give you a bit for every possible value :-)

As @jxh suggests, for 256 bytes you can construct a table to shift off bits which cannot match.  Construction of the table requires something like:

```
enum { patt = 0xA7 } ;
int8_t sht[256] ;

for (int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; ++i)
  {
    int8_t  s ;
    uint8_t b, m ;

    b = i ;
    s = 0 ;
    m = 0xFF ;

    while (b != (patt & m))
      {
        b >>= 1 ;
        m >>= 1 ;
        s  += 1 ;
      } ;

    sht[i] = s ;
  } ;
```

And then to use it, something like:

```
  uint16_t data ;
  int8_t a, s ;

  s = 0 ;
  a = -1 ;

  while (1)
    {
      int8_t t ;

      t = sht[data & 0xFF] ;

      if (t == 0)
        {
          a = s ;
          break ;
        }

      s += t ;
      if (s > 8)
        break ;

      data >>= t ;
    } ;
```

This accumulates in `s` the location of the 0xA7, but even if you don't need that, it's useful because it stops the loop.

Doing a little timing on random values, I found the simple shift approach takes about 3 times as long as the shift-table, and about 5.5 times as long as the bit-vector lookup approach.

[For completeness: if the pattern you are looking for were to be < 0x80, then you'd need to change the mask (currently `0xFF`) and the maximum useful shift (currently `8`).]